# php preg_replace from [[ to ]]

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a text like this:

```
$t = [[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=HomePage|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]]
[[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image030 jpg.png|141px|United Kingdom images gbr image030 jpg.png]]
[[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=Contact|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]];
```

and I want to add [noinclude] before text that has **|link=** between **[[** and **]]** and add [/noinclude] after the **]]**. So I want to add it to the first and third image. When I try it like this:

```
preg_replace('/\[\[Image:(.*?)\]\]/', '[noinclude][[Image:$1]][/noinclude]', $t);
```

it wraps all 3 images. And when I try it like this:

```
preg_replace('/\[\[Image:(.*?)\|link=(.*?)\]\]/', '[noinclude][[Image:$1|link=$2]][/noinclude]', $t);
```

the result is:

```
[noinclude][[File:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=ADI|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]][/noinclude]
[noinclude][[File:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]]
[[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=ADI|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]][/noinclude]
```

so it adds my tags correctly to the first one, but when it gets to the second image, it doesn't stop at **]]** of the second image, but continues to the **]]** of the third image (as it's looking for the **|link**)

How can I force it to stop at **]]**, if there is **|link=** between **[[ ]]** ?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
And what if the text is more complicated? Like this:

```
$t = '<span class="United Kingdomtemplate_colour">Additional remarks</span><br> <br> Green sign with white and yellow text with  blue plate with white text displaying that the indicated direction(s) lead to a motorway. [[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=Home Page|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]]<br>White sign with black text with  blue plate with white text displaying that the indicated direction(s) lead to a motorway. [[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image046 jpg.png|292px|United Kingdom images gbr image046 jpg.png]]<br> <br> <span style="vertical-align: top;">White sign with black text with  blue plate with white text displaying that the indicated direction(s) lead to a motorway. </span> [[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image2550 jpg.png|368px|United Kingdom images gbr image2550 jpg.png|link=Contact]]';
```

Comment: Seems to work for me, I tried you code here https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

Comment: Try to replace [`\[\[Image:[^]]+link=[^]]+]]` with `[noinclude]$0[/noinclude]`](https://regex101.com/r/vB0tL5/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following regex

```
~(\[\[Image.*\|link\=.*\]\])~
```

This'll capture those links which contains `|link=` between `[[Image` and `]]`. So your code looks like as

```
echo preg_replace("~(\[\[Image.*\|link\=.*\]\])~","[noinclude]$1[/noinclude]",$str);
```

Comment: Thanks Uchiha! But what to do when the text is more complicated? I've just updated my original question. When I run your code, it doesn't add the ending [/noinclude] correctly - it adds [/noinclude] to the very end of the text...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_split()` togethter with `strpos()`:

```
$t = '[[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=HomePage|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]][[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image030 jpg.png|141px|United Kingdom images gbr image030 jpg.png]][[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=Contact|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]]';
$n = array_filter(preg_split('/(?=\[\[)/', $t, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
foreach($n AS $key => $value){
    if(strpos($value, '|link') !== false){
        $n[$key] = '[noinclude]'.$value.'[/noinclude]';
    }
}
$t = implode($n);
```

Final result is:

```
[noinclude][[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=HomePage|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]][/noinclude]
[[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image030 jpg.png|141px|United Kingdom images gbr image030 jpg.png]]
[noinclude][[Image:United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png|141px|link=Contact|United Kingdom images gbr image031 jpg.png]][/noinclude]
```

Comment: Thanks Mitkosoft! But what to do when the text is more complicated? I've just updated my original question. When I run your code, it doesn't add the ending [/noinclude] after first image - it adds it somewhere further in the text...

Comment: My answer was based on your exact input. In your updated case you should use regex for sure - check the solution of @Uchiha, +1 from me for him.